# Tasklist total memory of specific proces with subprocesses windows

Tags: batch-file, memory, command-prompt, tasklist

I'm trying to log the memory usage of browsers for exemple for Chrome / Firefox etc.

For Firefox I can simply use this little command line:

```
tasklist /fo csv /fi "imagename eq firefox.exe" > DumpResults.csv
```

And this will nicely result with one proces and its usage. But when applying this train of thoughts to Chrome you'll get around 4 processes even when you did a clean launch of Chrome. Is there any way to sum the results?

Sorry for the stupid question but it's my first attempt to create a bat file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
set sum=0
for /f "tokens=5 delims=," %%x in ('tasklist /fo csv /nh /fi "imagename eq chrome.exe"') do (
  for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=.K " %%a in (%%x) do set /a sum+=%%a%%b%%c%%d
)
echo Sum Chrome = %sum%
```

Maybe you have to adapt the delimiters to your local settings. Output on my computer is like:

```
C:\Users> tasklist /fo csv /nh /fi "imagename eq chrome.exe"
"chrome.exe","7744","Console","1","86.388 K"
"chrome.exe","7784","Console","1","1.312 K"
"chrome.exe","7920","Console","1","50.188 K"
...
```

Comment: I've got the same output but the script returns  || The system cannot find the file 92. || Sum Chrome = 0   ||      The cannot find happens around 6 times so that's as many as chrome processes there are running atm but can't find a way to put this in code... sorry

Comment: just copy-pasted my code from above to a fresh batfile. Works fine for me. Did you change anything? Try `... %%a in ("%%~x") ...`

Comment: That fixed it for me altho I don't really understand it, thanks alot! I'm gonna try to learn bit by bit what you gave me! :)

Comment: Removed my question, I just had to put in "," in the echo between the values I wanted to seperate, sorry for bothering you :)

Answer (score 3):

An alternative…

```
@Echo Off
Set "sum=0"
For /F "Tokens=6-7 Delims=., " %%a In (
    'TaskList /NH /FI "ImageName Eq chrome.exe"') Do Set/A sum+=%%a%%b
Set sum
Pause
```

…prevents using two loops

Comment: Clean solution :) Thank you!